# Simulating the game of BlackJack in Dart

Tags: dart, probability, blackjack

I tried writing a program in [DartPad](http://DartPad.dev) to simulate a series of Blackjack games where the player follows exactly the same strategy as the dealer i.e. hitting until the score exceeds 16. Now according to the article [here](https://www.ace-ten.com/blackjack-basics/odds/) and [here](https://wizardofodds.com/ask-the-wizard/blackjack/probability/) the house should have at least 5% advantage over the player. How do I account for this advantage? Also why does playing exactly like the dealer make the odds equal in favor of the player. Here is the aforementioned program: -

```
/*
 * PROGRAM SIMULATIING BLACKJACK
 * 
 * PLAYER KEEPS HITTING UNTIL THE SCORE EXEEDS 16
 * 
 * RESULTS:
 * 
 * PLAYER WINS ~ 43.8% OF TIMES
 * MATCH IS DRAW ~ 12.4% OF TIMES
 * DEALER WINS ~ 43.8% OF TIMES
 * 
 * PROGRAM DOESN'T TAKE INTO ACCOUNT THE CARDS ALREADY DISTRIBUTED
 * I.E. DISTRIBUTES CARDS FROM A FULL DECK OF CARDS TO BOTH THE 
 * PLAYER AND THE DEALER.
 * 
 * */

import 'dart:math';

class Player {
  int score;
  bool hardHand, busted;

  Player() {
    this.score = 0;
    this.hardHand = false;
    this.busted = false;
  }

  void hit() {
    int randomNumber = Random().nextInt(13) + 1;

    if (randomNumber > 10) {
      this.score += 10;
    } else if (randomNumber == 1) {
      this.score += 11;
      this.hardHand = true;
    } else {
      this.score += randomNumber;
    }

    if (this.score > 21) {
      if (this.hardHand) {
        this.hardHand = false;
        this.score -= 10;
      }
    }

    if (this.score > 21) this.busted = true;
  }
}

void main() {
  int turns = 100000;
  int wins = 0, loses = 0, draws = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player dealer = new Player();

    while (player1.score < 17) {
      player1.hit();
    }

    while (dealer.score < 17) {
      dealer.hit();
    }

    //print("score: ${player1.score} busted: ${player1.busted}");

    if (player1.score > dealer.score) {
      wins++;
    } else if (player1.score == dealer.score) {
      draws++;
    } else {
      loses++;
    }
  }

  double winPercent = (wins / (wins + loses + draws)) * 100;
  double drawPercent = (draws / (wins + loses + draws)) * 100;
  double lossPercent = 100 - winPercent - drawPercent;

  print("WIN Percentage: $winPercent");
  print("DRAW Percentage: $drawPercent");
  print("LOSS Percentage: $lossPercent");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be deviating from the blackjack rules as I read them in the provided links.

1. If you bust, you lose. The dealer doesn't have to do anything after that, and you've lost even if they'd bust too. So, you need the rules to start with `if (player1.busted) { loses++; } else ...`.
2. If you don't bust, but the dealer does, you win. So `if (dealer.busted) { wins++; } else ...`.
3. You count draws, but having the same score means that the dealer wins, so `if (dealer.score >= player1.score) { loses++; } else { wins++; }`.
4. Finally, you count "hard hands", but miss the possibility of having two aces, so I'd probably *count* aces instead of just having a single boolean. That's unlikely to actually matter much.

Fixing for that, I get something like:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class Player {
  int score = 0;
  int acesHigh = 0;

  void hit() {
    int randomNumber = Random().nextInt(13) + 1;

    if (randomNumber > 10) {
      score += 10;
    } else if (randomNumber == 1) {
      score += 11;
      acesHigh++;
    } else {
      score += randomNumber;
    }

    if (score > 21) {
      if (acesHigh > 0) {
        acesHigh--;
        score -= 10;
      }
    }
  }
  
  bool get busted => score > 21;
}

void main() {
  int turns = 100000;
  int wins = 0, losses = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
    Player player1 = new Player();
    while (player1.score < 17) {
      player1.hit();
    }
    if (player1.busted) {
      losses++;
      continue;
    }

    Player dealer = new Player();
    while (dealer.score < 17) {
      dealer.hit();
    }
    if (dealer.busted) {
      wins++;
      continue;
    }
    
    // print("score: ${player1.score} busted: ${player1.busted}");

    if (player1.score > dealer.score) {
      wins++;
    } else {
      losses++;
    }
  }

  assert(wins + losses == turns);
  double winPercent = (wins / turns) * 100;
  double lossPercent = 100 - winPercent;

  print("WIN Percentage: $winPercent");
  print("LOSS Percentage: $lossPercent");
}
```

which usually gives me around 40.8% wins and 59.2% losses.

The house always wins.